# Unity struct variable of type struct array initializing

Tags: unity-game-engine, struct, artificial-intelligence, montecarlo, monte-carlo-tree-search

I'm having an issue with my struct. I'm working on an implementation of the Monte Carlo Tree Search algorithm and I created a struct called Node which has specific variables.
Now I need to store parent as well as child objects of type node. Since a node can be a parent for other nodes, but also child of a node this is important.

```
[System.Serializable]
public struct Node
{
    public Transform[,] CurrentField_V;
    public Transform[,] CurrentField_H;
    public Transform[,] CurrentField_Boxes;
    public Node [] nodeChildren;
    public Node [] parent;
    public int result;
    public bool isTerminal;
    public bool alreadyChecked;
    public int y;
    public int x;
    public int visitTimes;
```

This is where the issue is:

```
public Node Expand(Node v)
{
    Debug.Log("Start EXPANSION");
    //create a new node
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.parent[0] = v; //---------> NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION
    newNode.CurrentField_V = v.CurrentField_V;
    newNode.CurrentField_H = v.CurrentField_H;
    v.nodeChildren[counter] = newNode;//---------> NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION
    newNode.visitTimes++;


}
```

does anyone have a clue how i can solve this issue?

Comment: You need to show your constructor, you create a new node but are you creating a new array for the parents and children? Declaring them only sets the reference, you still need something like : parent = new Node[size];

Comment: `newNode.parent = new Node[1]; newNode.parent[0] = v;` or initialize it in the constructor.